# Locating Basemaps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, topography, usgs, quickmapservices

I've been attempting to download a usable basemap for *USGS Topography* for quite some time. Going through the USGS procedure to acquire the map has not worked to date.

*Quickmapservices* and *Openlayer* plugin have only given me a black layer that does not work.

I'm also trying to download a shapefile for *FEMA Floodplain Zones*. Its been a very frustrating process and even after calling and going through the steps, nothing seems to work.

Comment: This is for QGIS*

Comment: Can you give a link to https://qms.nextgis.com/ service of *USGS Topography* where you get black layer? Do you inform service author about such error?

Answer (score 2):

Any of the USGS Topo Map Services from an ArcGIS Server instance can be consumed in QGIS via a WMS service.

For example, this web map: https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=931d892ac7a843d7ba29d085e0433465#!

...comes from this service: https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer

And has a link to the WMTS: https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

In QGIS, in the Browser window, make a new WMS/WMTS connection, using the WMTS link in the URL above. You'll get a connection and can add the map to your project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did it work for you?